# Proper way to design a series of OO Classes

Tags: php, oop, interface, model

I'm designing a system to interact with several different [LMSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system) (currently: Moodle, BlackBoard, Canvas). Currently, I have something that looks like the following:

```
ModelFactory
     |
MoodleModel     -\
BlackboardModel -|-- LMSInterface
CanvasModel     -/
```

From my endpoints, I'm doing

```
$mf = new ModelFactory($app, $ioc);
```

and `ModelFactory` determines (from `$app`) which of the Models to load, creates it, and allows calls to the backend models via `$mf->model->`.

In each of these backend models, I have methods like `get_courses`, `get_categories`, `get_quizzes`, etc. I now have a need to get the questions from a quiz.

My initial thought was to just add a `get_quiz_questions` to my backend models, but that seems dirty.

Is there a "suggested" way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

What does `get_quizzes` return ? A `Quiz` object ? If so, you could simply add `get_questions` to this object and not worry about your hierarchy of LMS objects. Your `Quiz` object would be a backend-agnostic representation of the quiz.

Comment: `get_quizzes` returns an array of plain objects. I'm entertaining ideas of making it (and their ilk) return specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

Think it should be pretty much depend from the objects you operating with and the models. If the questions is 100% part of the quiz, and not a data of Model then it will be confusing to allow model returning quiz questions. But if quiz questions is just a first level sudobjects of your model - then it pretty normal to allow model returning questions.

Also, if for example quiz is some complex object and in possible to return questions and save some resources to not constructing/sending quiz instance. In other cases I agree with Brian.

And also, if you LMS interface is some kind of remote interface - then you need to make it as simple as possible and guarantee that it returns only whole objects avoiding micro calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `get_quiz_questions` to the backend models, that would be fine. I would expect such a function (that gives an array of the quiz questions) to return generic objects (likely using an [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), or maybe [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) depending on the rest of the design).